# PHP Short hand tags 7.x

Tags: php, php-shorttags

Just wondering, I have a codeigniter project that I have been asked to do some work on. Im also trying to (where I can) prepare the project for upgrading to php 7.x (currently on 5).

One thing Im confused about is the use of php short tags. I love them but it seems they are being removed in 7?

So my question is, should I be removing them? The problem is, they make the code so much more readable, why are they removing it?

So for example:

```
<?php if ($product->price_discounted > 0)
{
    echo "<p class='discounted price'>" . $product->price_discounted . "</p>" 
}
?>
```

vs

```
<? if ($product->price_discounted > 0): ?>
    <p class='discounted price'><?= $product->price_discounted ?></p>
<? endif; ?>
```

I would much rather the second version, but whenever I run my project on php7 these don't work. Am I missing something or are they really removed?

FYI: I have short tags on in php.ini

Comment: The shorthand tags are still working in PHP 7. Take a look at the documentation page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: removed: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: did you restarted  your Apache server. ? After made changes in ini file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the correct php.ini being loaded?

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Check for Loaded Configuration File

Comment: Ok i'm slighlty embarrased, seems i have 2 installs of php on my machine, one with phpstorm and another with Laragon and I was editing the wrong one. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

## Important Update:

Short tags are **not deprecated** anymore.
Despite the RFC passing, some controversy ensued and the PHP internals group refused to implement it<sup>[1](https://news-web.php.net/php.internals/106407)</sup>. Check out the migration guide for confirmation:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.php

---

### Original Post:

Short open tags are deprecated in PHP 7.4, and will be removed in PHP 8.

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_php_short_tags

Also, the short echo (`<?=`) is not part of `short_open_tag` as of 5.4. It is always available, and is not part of the deprecation.

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/shortags

Comment: That second RFC did not pass so I've removed that bit from the answer. The first RFC was ignored and nothing changed.

Answer (score 6):

Shorthand tags are still in PHP7, the tags being removed are:

- `<% opening tag`
- `<%= opening tag with echo`
- `%> closing tag`
- `(<script\s+language\s*=\s*(php|"php"|'php')\s*>)i opening tag`
- `(</script>)i closing tag`

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_alternative_php_tags