# How do I add a PHP (or similar) variable into HTML in a Wordpress page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a dropdown FAQ page on my website that *can* be edited with Elementor, but I’m knowledgeable of accessing files in my child theme etc, though have some confusion as to how to actually apply PHP (or similar) variables into my standard HTML section in Elementor.

If there are any video recommendations (I’ve looked, but I’m not exactly sure what it is I am trying to do here as my server-side knowledge is near zero) I'd greatly appreciate a link. Also, please feel free to correct me if I’m missing something spectacularly here (such as this being in the incorrect coding language altogether).

```
<p class="section heading">
  My first section goes here.
</p>
```

Instead of `first` I would like the ability to add a variable that I can change only once (this heading will be used on many pages)

```
<p class="section heading">
  My <?php $myVariable ?> section goes here.
</p>
```

Comment: If you want the value of that variable to show up on the page, you need to actually output it e.g. `<?php echo $myVariable; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

**1. Use echo**

Example : `<?php echo $variable; ?>`

**2. Use short version**
If you are using php version < 7.4 (this function removed in php8 > [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55973993/12616640))

In this case the php function short_open_tag should be turned on in php.ini file.

Example : `<?=$variable?>`

Comment: I don't believe the latter part of #2 is correct anymore. Short tags were only required in 5.6 I think.

Comment: In php 7 some of tags are removed but not tag i used. Removed tags are:
    <% opening tag
    <%= opening tag with echo
    %> closing tag
    (<script\s+language\s*=\s*(php|"php"|'php')\s*>)i opening tag
    (</script>)i closing tag

Comment: @user3783243 but if you using php8 they are removed :) thank you i will fix my answer

Comment: I believe `<?=` works in every version of PHP > 5.6. The short tags directive was only required for 5.6. Prior to 5.6 that shorthand didn't exist, when introduced it required the directive.